# Cache/Session a Menu XML in Classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic

I've got a Classic ASP application with 5 different classes of user who might have access to 5 different (some overlapping) sets of pages. I've got an XML structure that works, but I don't want to parse it each time.

Would it be better to cache the XML in session, the rendered HTML in session? (menus are typically a UL/LI), or do something even more simple than even use XML?

Answer (score 0):

When using session you're using alot of memory, its either that, or storing it in a DB with a hierarchical approach, then displaying the menu with a recursive method using `<ul><li>`.

Comment: I wouldn't think it would be that much - maybe Application-level. But I want to avoid any awful practices.

Comment: why not in a txt file on the server then instead of a session, i just don't see that kind of stuff going into a session, but depends how many people will use it, etc.

Comment: that's not a bad idea. i suppose i could just feed it from the database, but once someone logs in their menus are static.

Comment: Why not save the .xml file on the server, and give each xml object attributes, like `adminuser=1` `standarduser=0`